# ROS driver for phase space motion

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear All

Could you please provide me ROS driver for phase space motion?
I can not find it in ROS page!

Your Sincerely

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/79471/ros-driver-for-phase-space-motion/) by [Zargol](https://answers.ros.org/users/6711/zargol/) on ROS Answers with karma: 206 on 2013-09-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

OK! I solved the problem! In phase space computer, there is compiled library and sample c code, which can run them in ROS!

---

Originally posted by [Zargol](https://answers.ros.org/users/6711/zargol/) with karma: 206 on 2013-09-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1